# Automation error or Error 462 in excel VBA code

Tags: excel, vba, automation, runtime

I get an error "-2147417848 (80010108) run time error with the following code im using in Excel VBA":

```
sub import()

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    On Error GoTo error

    Dim App As New excel.Application 
    Dim wbImport As Workbook
    Set wbImport = App.Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "example.xlsm")

       'DATA COPY
       Dim Lastrow As Integer
       Lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
       ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA").Range("A2:AM" & Lastrow).Copy
       wbImport.Worksheets("DATA").Range("a2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 
       wbImport.Worksheets("CONFIG").Shapes("pdv").Visible = False


  wbImport.Close SaveChanges:=True 
  App.CutCopyMode = False 
  App.Quit 
  MsgBox "OK"

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  

error:

   App.CutCopyMode = False 
   wbImport.Close SaveChanges:=True 
   App.Quit 
    
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "FAIL"

End sub
```

And recently found out that, by adding

```
Set App = Nothing
```

after

```
 App.Quit
```

It gives me "Error 462", but I have no clue why. Debugging just runs normally, error prompts at the very end, after msgboxes.

Comment: Why are you creating a new application?

Comment: @BigBen literally no idea, reused and adapted a code from this webpage. Also tried with Set App = CreateObject("Excel.Application") and got runtime 91.

Comment: @BigBen you're right, its excel. I wanted to open the file without showing (hidden)

Comment: You quit the app. It is no longer in memory. How can the object terminate with `nothing` if it is no longer running. Setting objects to nothing is voodoo programming. There is no need.

Comment: @user14797724 Thank you, I'm still learning and I appreciate your contribution. Can you help with my issue? :D

Comment: Remove the line.

Comment: @user14797724 That doesn't solve the topic's problem.

Comment: There is no need to ever `set X = nothing`. It is done automatically at `end sub`. **All** your errors have the same cause, you keep accessing things you freed from memory. Remove extraneous `app.quit`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226679/discussion-between-francisco-j-perez-and-user14797724).

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is not the best solution but are the ones I found:

1- No need to  `Dim App As New excel.Application` to open an excel file in the background.

Screenupdating property right after and before opening is enough to not show the process:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wbImport As Workbook
Set wbImport = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\example.xlsm" 

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

2- I forgot to add `Exit sub` right before "error:" handle.

Final code:

```
    sub import()
    On Error GoTo error
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
      
        Dim wbImport As Workbook
        Set wbImport = App.Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "example.xlsm")
    
           'DATA COPY
           Dim Lastrow As Integer
           Lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
           ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA").Range("A2:AM" & Lastrow).Copy
           wbImport.Worksheets("DATA").Range("a2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 
           wbImport.Worksheets("CONFIG").Shapes("pdv").Visible = False
    
      wbImport.Close SaveChanges:=True 
      MsgBox "OK"

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  
exit sub 

error:

wbImport.Close SaveChanges:=True   
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "FAIL"

End sub
```